# Animating a UIView to a value without a specified duration

Tags: ios, core-animation, duration

I want to animate a sub-classed `UIView` using Core Animation. The oddity in my case is that I want the animation to run a fixed amount every frame and not by the duration. So animating from 100 -> 200 should take longer than 100 -> 50, but the "velocity" of the view should be constant. My code currently looks like this:

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
animation.duration = 0.4;

[[self layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];

self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 100);
```

It this possible? How would it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just compute the desired time from the desired movement? Something like:

```
CGFloat distanceToTimeFactor = 0.1;
CGPoint current = self.center;
CGPoint new = CGPointMake(100,100);

CGFloat xDist = (new.x - current.x);
CGFloat yDist = (new.y - current.y);
CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));

CGFloat duration = distance * distanceToTimeFactor;
```

And then animate with that duration.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with this solution.